# Suppose we have two functions that meet at one point, does this mean that their derivatives would also meet at one point?

Tags: calculus

The title is wrong, I'm aware of that, however, i just encountered one question that says it's correct. I must be missing something, please help me find it. Thank you all for your help.

Given two functions $h(x) = p-\cos(x)$ and $k(x) = \sin^2(x)$ in the interval $[0,\pi]$ determine the set of $p$ so that the graphs of the two functions meet within the given interval.

My thoughts: usually the way to find the answer to such problems is simply to set the two equations equal to each other, however in this case, there is the variable p so we can't do that. but after seeing how the graphs look, I thought to take the derivative of the two functions and set them equal to each other which also turns out to be correct. However, I don't know why it is correct since we can't do this in all cases.

My intuition tells me its a very simple thing that I am somehow ignoring, but I just don't know what it is, so again thank you for your help

Comment: Matching derivatives won't make the graphs meet. For instance $f(x)=x$, and $g(x)= x +10$, have the same derivative (identically), but never meet.

Comment: There are many parameters $p$ for which those two functions will meet on $(0,\pi)$, so it is strange that the question says "determine *the* parameter $p$". You should add details about how exactly you used the derivatives to come up with an answer. But either way, having some strategy work for two particular functions doesn't suggest that it should work for general functions. The strategy might crucially rely on the specific functions here, or just be a coincidence.

Comment: Changing $p$ translates the graph of $h$ vertically. So you can imagine starting with a large value of $p$ and lowering it, lowering the graph of $h$ onto the graph of $k$. When they first touch at a single point, then (assuming they touch somewhere in the middle and not at an end point $x=0$ or $x=\pi$) they will be tangent, so you will not only have $h(x)=k(x)$, but also $h'(x)=k'(x)$ at the point where they touch. The same happens when you raise $h$ up from below, and will give you the range of values of $p$ for which they intersect at least once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose any number $\theta$ in the interval $(0,\pi)$ and let $p_\theta=\sin^2(\theta)+\cos(\theta)$. Then $(\theta,\sin^2(\theta))$ is a point of intersection of the graphs of $p_\theta-\cos(x)$ and $\sin^2(x)$. So this shows that there are *many* parameters $p$ so that $p-\cos(x)$ and $\sin^2(x)$ have a point of intersection in the interval $(0,\pi)$. Indeed, I can find a parameter for any choice of $\theta$ in $(0,\pi)$.

What you did was narrow in on $\theta=\pi/3$ by setting the derivatives equal to each other. You then computed $p_{\pi/3}=\sin^2(\pi/3)+\cos(\pi/3)=\frac{3}{4}+\frac{1}{2}=\frac{5}{4}$. So in this case, I would say that using derivatives was a red herring.

Now, you could say that for $\theta=\pi/3$, you get an intersection point for both the original functions and their derivatives.  This is only choice of $\theta$ where this happens unless you allow the endpoints $0$ or $\pi$ as the $x$-value. If you allowed these values you would get $(0,0)$ or $(\pi,0)$ as an intersection point for both $\pm 1-\cos x$ and $\sin^2(x)$, as well as their derivatives. These solutions show up in your calculations at the point where you simplified $2\sin x\cos x= \sin x$ to $\cos x=\frac{1}{2}$ since you have to account for $\sin x = 0$.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explaination. However i still have a few follow up questions. 1) why would (\theta, sin^2(\theta) be the intersection point of the two graphs? 2) I actually have a few other similar questions where we have to find the intersection point by setting both the equations and their derivatives equal to each other, but after seeing your explaination i  realised there are actually infinite possible intersection points, does this mean whoever came up with these questions made a mistake?     Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: The two functions are $h(x)=p_\theta-\cos x$ and $k(x)=\sin^2(x)$. I defined $p_\theta$ to be $\sin^2\theta+\cos\theta$. Therefore $h(\theta)=p_\theta-\cos\theta=\sin^2\theta=k(\theta)$. So $h$ and $k$ take the same value at $\theta$, which means we have an intersection point of the graphs. I can't say for sure about your problems but either there is more context that rules out other solutions, or the person just meant to write "determine **a** parameter $p$ so that..."

Answer (score 0):

The following figure could have been drawn by hand. It shows the curves $y=h_p(x):=p-\cos x$ and $y=k(x):=\sin^2 x$ for the maximal and the minimal values of $p$ that give $\geq1$ points of intersection in the interval $0\leq x\leq\pi$. These special values  $p_\max$ and $p_\min$ lead to special "graphical" conditions that determine their values. In the case of $p_\max$ we indeed have equalities $$h_p(x)=k(x)\qquad\wedge\qquad h_p'(x)=k'(x)$$
for a certain (unknown) $x$, whereas in the case of $p_\min$ we see that the incidence point is at $x=\pi$.

[image]